# Read content of files and check if values are same

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have one file located at C:\Users\abc\Desktop named BUIBNESSDATE.
File contents are

```
Updated on :
Thu Jan 23 04:05:00 IST 2014
ProfileBusinessDate=23/1/2014

NucleusBusinessDate=23/01/2014
```

I want script which will check if both have same date(ProfileBusi nessDate & NucleusBusinessDate )date are same. If both date are same then script should give message as OK else NotOk.

how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
set "file=C:\Users\abc\Desktop\BUIBNESSDATE"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (' find /i "profile" ^< "%file%" ' ) do set "p=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (' find /i "nucleus" ^< "%file%" ' ) do set "n=%%a"

if "%p%"=="%n%" (echo OK) else (echo NotOK)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "ppd="
SET "nbd="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21312106.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :process
)

IF NOT DEFINED ppd ECHO ProfileBusinessDate missing&GOTO :EOF 
IF NOT DEFINED nbd ECHO NucleusBusinessDate missing&GOTO :EOF

FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=/" %%a IN ("%ppd%") DO CALL :slz ppdd %%a&CALL :slz ppdm %%b&CALL :slz ppdy %%c
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=/" %%a IN ("%nbd%") DO CALL :slz nbdd %%a&CALL :slz nbdm %%b&CALL :slz nbdy %%c

IF "%ppdd%-%ppdm%-%ppdy%"=="%nbdd%-%nbdm%-%nbdy%" (ECHO OK) ELSE (ECHO NotOk)

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "$1=%line:*ProfileBusinessDate=%"
IF NOT "%$1%"=="%line%" SET "ppd=%$1:~1%"&GOTO :EOF 
SET "$1=%line:*NucleusBusinessDate=%"
IF NOT "%$1%"=="%line%" SET "nbd=%$1:~1%"&GOTO :EOF 
GOTO :EOF

:: suppress a leading 0

:slz
SET "$1=%2"
IF "%$1:~0,1%"=="0" (SET "%1=%$1:~1%") ELSE (SET "%1=%2")
GOTO :eof
```

Should do the task. I used `q21312106.txt` with your data as a source file.

Comment: I assumed the mismatch in the dates was a typo, and `1` was meant to be `01`

Comment: @foxidrive I assumed they weren't

Comment: That's obvious. :)  It wouldn't be likely that two different date formats were used in the same INI type file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextension disabledelayedexpansion
    set "pdb="
    set "nbd="
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (
        'findstr /b /l /c:"ProfileBusinessDate=" /c:"NucleusBusinessDate=" "c:\users\abc\desktop\buibnessdate"'
    ) do (
        if "%%a"=="ProfileBusinessDate" (set "pbd=%%b" ) else (set "nbd=%%b")
    )

    if "%pdb%"=="%nbd%" ( 
        echo OK 
    ) else ( 
        echo NOT OK 
    )
```

Search the file for the required lines, splitting them on equal sign and assigning the values to the adecuated variables. Then check if both variables hold the same content.